# Better way to find a specific asset?

Tags: gallery, assetfilemodel, getsegment, index, loop

I'm currently using a route to get a specific asset for a gallery section of my site. URL is similiar to http://craft.dev/place/place-name/gallery/1 (Where 1 is the number in the gallery.)

I'm currently doing the following in the template

```
{% extends '_layout' %}

{% set entry = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}

{% set image = entry.images[craft.request.getSegment(4) - 1] %}

{% block content %}

    {{image.getImg('featuredImage')}}

{% endblock %}
```

It works currently but is there a cleaner way to do it without the `- 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s definitely the way to do it!

I would set the URL segments to their own variables, to clean it up a little bit.

```
{% set entrySlug = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set imageOffset = craft.request.getSegment(4) - 1 %}
```

Also, probably a good idea to include the [section](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#section) param when fetching the entry, in case you have another entry in another section with the same slug.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('mySection').slug(entrySlug).first() %}
```

The only issue I can think of is, if the 4th segment is greater than the total number of assets, you’re going to get an error. You can grab the asset using the [offset](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets#offset) param instead, and check to see if anything is returned:

```
{% set image = entry.images.offset(imageOffset).first() %}

{% if not image %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Brandon, is it save to omit the brackets in `first()` and in all other empty parameters?

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Sure. There’s a _slight_ performance improvement if you include them, because Twig knows for sure that it’s a method, so it doesn’t have to figure that out for itself every time, but it’s a micro-optimization at best.

Comment: Cool! yeah I added in that section param shortly after. Is there any possibility of adding what I've done into a method for future users. Not sure how often the use case would be necessary but having a clean(er) way to call a particular asset from a field, like `file.nth(n)` would be quite useful!

Comment: @SeanO'Grady I like that `nth()` idea. Adding to the list :)

Comment: @SeanO'Grady That [`nth()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#nth) function made it into [Craft 2.2](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2579) ;)

Comment: Awesome news Brandon!